# A tap on a message does not open the app page in AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, imessage, imessage-extension

The application I develop, which contains iMessage extension got published in AppStore recently.
When I send messages with my extension to people without this app installed, they tap on the message, and get AppStore view, opened at "Featured" page.
According to documentation, it should open my app page.

Are there any conditions required for this to work?
Any rules to follow regarding bundle IDs, names, entitlements, anything?

It seems to work for other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turned out to be my own fault. For this feature to work properly, the sender must have your app downloaded from the AppStore. Ad-hoc or debug builds somehow fail to add the proper magic to the custom messages.